# pygobject tree view shown empty after loading and populating it at runtime

Tags: python, treeview, gtk, pygobject

This is my first time i needed to post here after a long time of reading useful answers.

in this problem i am using **python3** and **pygobject**. i just started learning pygobject.

my program consists of a stack which contains a button. when the button is pressed, i create a list store and a tree view and make, add it to the stack and make it visible.

- what i **expect** is **when i press the button, i see the tree view**.
- what **happens** is **when i press the button, no changes to the interface happens**.
- when i press the button again, the stack changes to the treeview. **it should have happened from the first time**.

I have seen this behaviour in windows and linux.

here is my code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

#list of tuples for each software, containing the software name, initial release, and main programming languages used
software_list = []

class TreeViewFilterWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        #init window
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Treeview Filter Demo")
        self.resize (500, 500)

        #create stack
        self.stack = Gtk.Stack()
        self.add (self.stack)

        #create button. when pressed, it will create tree view and show it
        #add button to stack
        button = Gtk.Button (label='create tree')
        button.connect ('clicked', self.create_tree)
        self.stack.add (button)

        #init tree view to none
        #button is pressed while there is a treeview, no need to create it. just make it visible
        self.treeview = None


    def create_tree (self, widget):
        #if tree view is none, create it
        if not self.treeview:
            #Creating the ListStore model
            self.software_liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, int)

            #creating the treeview
            self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(self.software_liststore)

            #adding two columns
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('software', renderer, text=0)
            self.treeview.append_column(column)
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('release year', renderer, text=1)
            self.treeview.append_column(column)

            #add to stack
            self.stack.add(self.treeview)

            #append 1 column
            self.software_liststore.append (('pitivi', 2005))

        #set visible
        self.stack.set_visible_child (self.treeview)

        #if show_all is not called, the tree view is never shown
        self.stack.show_all()


win = TreeViewFilterWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

what am i missing? is it a bug?
also do i need to call show_all everytime i add new widgets?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a call to `self.treeview.show_all()` once you create the treeview, for example after the call to `self.software_liststore.append` (but still inside the `if`). You can remove the call to `self.stack.show_all()`, since the stack is already shown, which is ensured by the call to `win.show_all()` at top-level.

It is not obvious why your call to `self.stack.show_all()` doesn't encompass the tree view that has been added to the stack. If you change the `Gtk.Stack` to a `Gtk.HBox` and `add()` to `pack_start()`, the explicit call to `show_all` on the tree view is no longer required. That this doesn't work with `GtkStack` might be a GTK bug or the result of the asynchronous nature of transition implemented by `set_visible_child`.

Comment: Thank you very much.
What you said worked on the example above. However, it is not working on my actual program which i feel is too long to be put here and includes glade files. I was trying to see where the problem is exactly but could not get the exact same behaviour with a simple program yet. Thank you.